# Some updates visible in public Facebook permalinks, not accessible in Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Consider the publicly-viewable

http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10150759764293420&id=655923419

this is a status update with ID 655923419_10150759764293420 for user 655923419, correct?

When I look at that user's statuses, with OR without a client or app token via the open graph explorer, I get, for

https://graph.facebook.com/655923419_10150759764293420

simply the result 'false'

what does that mean, and how should i access that status update?

The central question here:

If there's a public permalink for an open graph object, how do I access the same data via the open graph apis -- an example query that works for the permalink at the top of this post would be much appreciated!